# Passing a reference of an Activity

Tags: android

Hi guys I can't figure out why I cant get it to work, to check the CheckBox of an activity from within another class.

In the onCreate method of the activity I'm passing a reference of itself to another class

```
public MainActivity()
...
dbi = new DBPrefsInterface(this);
...
}

public DBPrefsInterface(Context ctx)
{
    MainActivity pma = (MainActivity)ctx;
    this.ma = pma;
}
```

Now I try to Check a checkbox which is placed on the activity

```
this.ma.cbx.setChecked(true);
```

but it isn't working.

It seems I didn't pass a reference, only a Copy of MainActivity.

Thanks in adcance

Comment: It is getting even more strange      this.ma.cbx.setClickable(true); does work,  this.ma.cbx.setChecked(false); does work    this.ma.cbx.setChecked(true); brings me a Null pointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you pass in the CheckBox itself? So your constructor becomes `public DBPrefsInterface(CheckBox cbx)` and you manipulate that reference.

Here is an example of a simple activity to demonstrate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.checkbox);

    CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    final DBPrefsInterface iface = new DBPrefsInterface(cbx);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            iface.toggle();
        }
    });

}

private class DBPrefsInterface {
    CheckBox cbx = null;

    public DBPrefsInterface(CheckBox cbx) {
        this.cbx = cbx;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        cbx.setChecked(cbx.isChecked());
    }
}
```

Comment: results in the same problem :( for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: I edited my answer with an example. If it still does not work please let me know how what it is that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a handler and a reference to the checkbox in the constructor of the other class

and make the handler send a message to the checkbox's original context

```
hanlder.post(new Runnable() {

@override
void run {
checkbox.setChecked(true);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to do this, but I think using the following constructor would do the work:

```
private MainActivity ma;
public DBPrefsInterface(MainActivity a){
    ma = a;
}
```

Then to set the checkbox (but checkbox needs to be public in order to work):

```
ma.cbx.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: I am doing it exactly this way,

Comment: It should work mate, you pass the reference of the activity. Then you have to make the checkbox public in your activity in order to access it this way